# I am trying to convert the following objective-c code to swift:

Tags: objective-c, swift, vk-sdk

```
    SVKShareDialogController * shareDialog = [VKShareDialogController new];
    shareDialog.text = @"Your share text here";
    shareDialog.otherAttachmentsStrings = @[@"https://vk.com/dev/ios_sdk"];
    [shareDialog presentIn:self];

//SWIFT
    var shareDialog = VKShareDialogController()
    shareDialog.text = "Your share text here"
    shareDialog.otherAttachmentsStrings = ["https://vk.com/dev/ios_sdk"]
```

But I get some errors saying that type "viewcontroller" does not conform to protocol "VKSdkDelegate".

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: That looks more like a problem in the `VKShareDialogController` class than a swift conversion issue. It just means that the class does not implement the `VKSdkDelegate` properly

Comment: import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, VKSdkDelegate {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are adopting the `VKSdkDelegate` protocol in your `ViewController` class, but you have not implemented one or more of the required methods. The [VKSdkDelegate reference](http://vkcom.github.io/vk-ios-sdk/Protocols/VKSdkDelegate.html) lists all required methods that you have to implement in your class.